# Call other WCF service inside the callback function at client side

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a simple WCF application with call back interface.
What I want is call other WCF service inside the callback function at client side.

But When I try to do , I get the exception

> DetailsSystem.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The server did not
>   provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused b y a contract
>   mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Here is the contracts:

```
   [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoAddition(int numberOne, int numberTwo);

        [OperationContract]
        double Pow(double number, double power);
    }

    public interface IMyServiceCallback
   {
    [OperationContract]
    void OnCallback(string result);
   }
```

Here is the simple Service Implementation

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class MyCustomService : IMyService
    {
        public void DoAddition(int numberOne, int numberTwo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now Do Addition called");

            var callback = OperationContext.Current.
            GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallback>();

            callback.OnCallback("The result is="  + numberOne + numberTwo );
        }

        public double Pow(double number, double power)
        {
            double result = 0;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Now Pow called");
                result= Math.Pow(number, power);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Error:" + e);
            }

            return result;

        }
    }
```

I host this as a service in a console

```
callServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService.MyCustomService));
callServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IMyService), new WSDualHttpBinding(), new Uri(GetUri()));
callServiceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Press  to terminate.\n\n");
Console.ReadLine();
```

At Client I wanted to call wcf service in a callback function such that

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
public class MyServiceCallback : IMyServiceCallback
    {
        public void OnCallback(string result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Server I got the result" + result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            double powValue = Service.Pow(2, 3);

            Console.WriteLine("Power=" + powValue);
        }

        public IMyService Service { get; set; }
    }
```

My Client Code is

```
var binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
var address = new EndpointAddress(GetUri());

var callback = new MyServiceCallback();
var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(callback);

var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyService>(instanceContext, binding, address);
IMyService callService = factory.CreateChannel();
callback.Service = callService;

callService.DoAddition(4,6);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `[ServiceContract]` decoration by your IMyServiceCallback interface.
And could you also change your operation contract `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]`

Comment: Sorry, I just forget to write. [already included] Actually my callback fuction is called by server OnCallBack, i got the result, but when i try to call other methods such as Pow, i got that exception

Comment: then I would set your Service property as static. so than you can use a primary service channel. Decoration [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] of your methods is a must-to in this case.

Comment: Not an elagant solution but it also does not work. I make my service at client static and put [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] on CallBack but still get same error with crash

Comment: cound you try on more decoration of your service :)[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]

Comment: PerSession,PerCall,Single ...No effect